# Ubuntu 22.04 puts login on secondary monitor. How can I change this to my primary, permanently

Tags: multiple-monitors, login, 22.04

If I log out, when I go to log back in I'm faced with a black screen because the login is on my secondary screen, my television, even when I'm not using that input.  I assume this is a bug or I've changed an obscure setting somewhere accidentally.  It is very annoying.  How can I change this behavior to always logging in on primary monitor?

Answer (score 1):

There are two locations to set your primary display.

1. SETTINGS, APPEARANCE look at the "Show On" below Icon size.
2. SETTINGS, DISPLAYS

If you find it switching on you still, odds are it's because the frequency of one or both of the monitors is too high resulting in it not being detected correctly (even if it works at that frequency most of the time).  Lower the frequencies and try that.  Those settings are also found in option 2 listed above.

Comment: One is a 60/120Hz television and one is a 144Hz Monitor.  Changing the signal frequency didn't make a difference.  Neither did options 1 or 2.  Seems like a bug that would be easy fix.  I declare my primary, the OS should be able to log that and act accordingly.

Comment: I have the same configuration.  55" TV @60 Hz and primary monitor @ 144 Hz.  If I am watching my TV with my Blue Ray player (not from Laptop) and I happen to reboot the laptop at the same time; when I am done watching TV and try to switch source back to laptop, it is undetected.  I have to change the frequency on my laptop to 59 hz until the screen kicks in, then I can switch it back to 60 Hz.